# Two form object on one page Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have simple page which is used for searching for beer. 
On main page we have form, with only one input and button

```
<form class="card card-sm" method="get" th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${beerFormObject}">
      <input class="form-control form-control-lg form-control-borderless" placeholder="Search beer" th:field="*{beerName}" type="search">
</form>
```

As you can see this is set to GET method and is using `beerFormObject`, which has only one string parameter called name and in addition action is taken to `/search`
Controller which takes care form `/search`

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public ModelAndView searchBeer(@ModelAttribute("beerFormObject") @Valid BeerFormObject beerFormObject,
                               @ModelAttribute("reviewFormObject") ReviewFormObject reviewFormObject,
                               BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("/index");
    }

    Beer beer = beerService.findByName(beerFormObject.getBeerName());

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/beer-search-result");
    modelAndView.addObject("beer", beer);
    return modelAndView;
}
```

and the thymeleaf `beer-search-result` page which display beer details looks :

```
<div class="container" th:if="${beer}">
    <br/>
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="margin: auto; display: block;">
                <img class="card-img img-responsive mx-auto d-block"
                     style="  display: block; max-width:200px; max-height:250px; width: auto; height: auto;"
                     th:src="${beer.getImageUrl()}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8" style="margin: auto; display: block;">
                <div class="card-block px-2">
                    <h4 th:text="${beer.getName()}">Name</h4>
                    <p th:text="${beer.getDescription()}">Description</p>
                    <p th:text="${beer.getFirstBrewed()}">First Brewed</p>
                    <p th:text="${beer.getAbv()}">Abv</p>
                    <p th:text="${beer.getIbu()}">Ibu</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--  user comment form -->
    <div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()" th:if="${reviewFormObject}" th:block>
        <div class="row" id="post-review-box">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form method="post" th:action="@{/review}" th:object="${reviewFormObject}">
                    <input id="beer-id" th:field="*{beerName}" th:value="${beer.getName()}" type="hidden">
                    <textarea class="form-control animated" cols="50" id="new-review" name="comment"
                              placeholder="Enter your review here..." rows="5" th:field="*{reviewText}"></textarea>

                    <div class="text-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span sec:authorize="isAnonymous()"> Please <a th:href="@{/login}">Login</a> to post review</span>

</div>
```

As you probably can see in controller method I am passing two model attributes, `BeerFormObject` which is ok, because I need to process what I want to look for. And in addition I do have here `ReviewFormObject`, because on the same page/fragment I have form tag, which is used for adding new comments to the beer.

And what I dont undestand is why do I need to have them both as method parameters? Action/controller which takes care for adding new reviews is in another controller, here I only want to display reviews and beer information.

How could I make it to use only reale needed atributes? Like below. Right know if I remove second parameter I am getting exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'reviewFormObject' available as request attribute`

```
@GetMapping("/search")
public ModelAndView searchBeer(@ModelAttribute("beerFormObject") @Valid BeerFormObject beerFormObject,
                               BindingResult result) {
```

One more thing I dont want to redirect user to use other page for posting comments/reviews.

Comment: have you tried to add modelAndView.addObject("reviewFormObject", new ReviewFormObject()); in searchBeer method?

Comment: @Erwin Yes it is working, but `modelAndView.addObject("reviewFormObject", new ReviewFormObject(beer.getName())); ` But I need to add to the form object beer name and second it still seems stupid

Comment: but you can remove the ReviewFormObject from the method parameter? As far as I know the ModelAndView need something like object allocation for the page that it will load.